# loading array from NSUserDefault issue

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

i want to load array from nsuserdefault and then i want to add something in that array and then after i want to update my nsuserdefault with newly updated array for that i am doing following

```
NSUserDefaults *defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if([defs valueForKey:@"Images"] )
{
    [appDelegate.arrayOfPaths addObject :[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [defs valueForKey:@"Images"]]];
}
[appDelegate.arrayOfPaths addObject:path];
NSLog(@"_arrayOfPaths%@",appDelegate.arrayOfPaths);
[defs setObject:appDelegate.arrayOfPaths forKey:@"Images"];
NSLog(@"%@",[defs valueForKey:@"Images"]);
[appDelegate.arrayOfPaths removeAllObjects];
```

so my issues is first when i load array with NSUserdefalut so it array get filed with one array containing one object(string), and then i update my array with new string and then add it in nsuserdefalut but so in nsuserdefalut first object is array with one string and another is only string, i dont want this. i want only one array in nsuserdefault with all string in it. plz tell me how to achieve this

Comment: i saw your page Michael i wanted to email you to say Hello but let me say Hello to you here :) just live man im totally agree with you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your line of code....

```
 [appDelegate.arrayOfPaths addObject :[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [defs valueForKey:@"Images"]]];
```

As like this to get all the strings inside one array in nsuser defaults...

```
 [appDelegate.arrayOfPaths addObjectsFromArray : [defs valueForKey:@"Images"]]];
```

This will meet your requirement.

Comment: bhanu Prakash the man who knows what really you want :)